# General formula for the elements of the ring $k[x_1, ... , x_n]$ of polynomials in several variables over a field $k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

By the ring of polynomials in the indeterminate, $x$, written
as $F[x]$, we mean the set of all symbols $a_0 + a_1x + · · ·
+ a_nx^n$ where $n$ can be any nonnegative integer and where the coefficients $a_1, a_2,..., a_n$ are all in field $F$.$[1]$

Similarly, what set of symbols do we mean when we say the ring $k[x_1, ..., x_n]$ of polynomials in several variables over a field $k$?

---

$[1]$ Topics in Algebra, I.N. Herstein, 2nd Edition, page No. 153

Comment: What do you think it means? If you had to guess.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the one variable case, but you need to be careful about what you really mean. For example, consider $k[x,y]$, the ring of polynomials in two variables. Usually this would mean that $xy=yx$, that is, it is commutative by definition so you can form polynomials as you typically think of them.

Contrast with the "free algebra" on $x$ and $y$ which is akin to a free group, where elements are basically linear combinations of words and $xy\ne yx$, $xyx \ne x^2y$ etc.